# Vertical scrolling text issue

Tags: html, css

I am using a scrolling vertical text in CSS with an example of 4 different text, but when it is reduced to 2, it shows invisible spaces, how could I make the code work for only 2 text ?

```
#tickr-box 
{
background: #D3D3D3;
max-width: 550px;
padding: 3px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.tickr-title 
{
color: #FFFFFF;
font: bold 18px arial, sans-serif;
background: #2A75C1; 
padding: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#tickr-scroll ul
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
vertical-align: baseline;
list-style: none;
}

#tickr-scroll 
{
background: #4E91D5;
height: 27px;
margin: 3px auto 0px auto;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#tickr-scroll li 
    {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal 18px arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 26px;
    }

#tickr-scroll a 
{
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

#tickr-scroll a:hover 
{
color: #CCFF99;
text-decoration: none;
}

#tickr-scroll ul
{
padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
-webkit-animation: tickr 12s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
-moz-animation: tickr 12s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
-ms-animation: tickr 12s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
animation: tickr 12s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
}

#tickr-scroll ul:hover {
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-ms-animation-play-state: paused;
animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes tickr {
0%   { margin-top: 0; }
25%  { margin-top: -26px; }
50%  { margin-top: -52px; }
75%  { margin-top: -78px; }
100% { margin-top: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes tickr {
0%   { margin-top: 0; }
25%  { margin-top: -26px; }
50%  { margin-top: -52px; }
75%  { margin-top: -78px; }
100% { margin-top: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes tickr {
0%   { margin-top: 0; }
25%  { margin-top: -26px; }
50%  { margin-top: -52px; }
75%  { margin-top: -78px; }
100% { margin-top: 0; }
}

@keyframes tickr {
0%   { margin-top: 0; }
25%  { margin-top: -26px; }
50%  { margin-top: -52px; }
75%  { margin-top: -78px; }
100% { margin-top: 0; }
}
```

And here is the HTML with list of 4 text where I need only 2 but scroll alternately, if possible to show infinite loop (it's currently showing 1st text, then 2nd, then 3rd, then 4th and to show the 1st again we see the 3 others while it is quickly scrolling to the top...)

```
<div id="tickr-box">
              <div id="tickr-scroll">
                <ul>
                  <li>text 1</li>
                  <li>text 2</li>
                  <li>text 3</li>
                  <li>text 4</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically you need to alter your `@keyframes`, such that you only have two offsets remaining (`0` for first text, `-26px` for second text). Then, also adapt the percentages to `0%` (start of animation), `50%` (middle of animation) and `100%` (end of animation):

```
@keyframes tickr {
  0%   { margin-top: 0; }
  50%  { margin-top: -26px; }
  100% { margin-top: 0; }
}
```

You also need to adjust the timing, instead of `12s` your animation only needs `6s` now:

```
#tickr-scroll ul {
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  animation: tickr 6s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
}
```

If you want to keep the ventor-specific CSS definitions (the ones prefixed `-webkit`, `-moz` and `-ms`), you have to alter them as well. I only used the stock @keyframes element in my code examples.

See working demo here: [JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/nubeyiwibi/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

The @keyframe tickr annotation in your css tells you the following:

```
0% --> at the start of the "animation" you have no margin-top (value =0)

25% --> at 25% progress of your animation you have margin-top with value = -26 px

and so on...
```

so that this does is it changes your margin-top value over time. 
As your code says the margin should go from 0 to -26px to -52px  to -78px and then back to 0 it goes through 4 items. If you want only two items just use this (to keep the same speed):

```
@keyframes tickr { 0%   { margin-top: 0; } 
                   25%  { margin-top: -26px; } 
                   50%  { margin-top: 0; } 
                   75%  { margin-top:  -26px; } 
                   100% { margin-top: 0; } }
```

if you call this:

```
@keyframes tickr { 0%   { margin-top: 0; } 
                   50%  { margin-top: -26px; } 
                   100%  { margin-top: 0; } }
```

it works the same way but the animation is slower.

You might want to have a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: Thank you, your answer was also correct for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want your code to work when there are 4 `<li>` or 2 or different number of `<li>`.
Also you want the first list item to be shown after the last one without passing through other list items.

Both are not possible with pure CSS.

You may use plugins like [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to achieve these and for other such customizations.